# Change default dateparcer output

Tags: python-3.x, date-parsing

I found dateparser as a great way to change natural language into dates. Now, I am trying to manipulate the output of the parser without success.

```
from dateparser import parse
import datetime

def pars():

    n = "in two days"
    x  = parse(n, settings={'TIMEZONE': 'US/Eastern'})
    print (x)
    >>> 2016-08-25 00:18:03.268506

   t = datetime.datetime(x)
   t.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
   print (t)

pars()
```

I get the error: TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.datetime)

Answer (score 0):

Many things are wrong with the code.

- `dateparser` returns `datetime.datetime` objects not some `int`s that is what `datetime.datetime` expects
- `strftime` does not update the `datetime.datetime` object in place, if you want to keep the string value it produces, assign it to some var.

`def pars():
    x = parse('in two days')
    t = x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    print 'datetime', x
    print 'strftime', t

>>> pars()
datetime 2016-09-30 23:34:07.863881
strftime 09/30/2016`